# Stubs with varying parameter

Tags: microsoft-fakes

How does one stub a method in the Fakes framework so that the return value varies based on the value of a parameter?

For example, given the following interface and test, how does one create a stub in the case when value = 1 so that the return value = "A" and when value = 2, the return value = "B":

```
public interface ISimple
{
  string GetResult(int value);
}

public class Sut
{
    ISimple simple;

    public Sut(ISimple simple) 
    {
        this.simple = simple;
    }

    public string Execute(int value)
    {
        return this.simple.GetResult(value);
    }
}

[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    StubISimple simpleStub = new StubISimple();
    simpleStub.GetResultInt32 = (value) => { return "A";} // Always returns "A"

    var sut = new Sut(simpleStub);

    // OK
    var result = sut.Execute(1)
    Assert.AreEqual("A", result);

    // Fail
    result = sut.Execute(2);
    Assert.AreEqual("B", result);
}
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution. I found a great resource on fakes over at Codeplex, which I'm sharing here for others to enjoy:
http://vsartesttoolingguide.codeplex.com/releases/view/102290

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    StubISimple simpleStub = new StubISimple();
    simpleStub.GetResultInt32 = (value) => { 
        switch(value) 
        {
            case "A":
            {
                return "A";
                break;
            }
            case "B":
            {
                return "B";
                break;
            {
        }
    }

    var sut = new Sut(simpleStub);

    // OK
    var result = sut.Execute(1)
    Assert.AreEqual("A", result);

    // OK
    result = sut.Execute(2);
    Assert.AreEqual("B", result);
}
```